# JavaScript error SCRIPT5039 and SCRIPT5009

Tags: javascript

Hi i am working on javascript my code is not working i.e especially in IE9. My code is 
  working fine in IE8,chrome,firefox. In IE9 I got 5039 error (var redeclaration) i just 
  comment that code again that code displays following Error.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'ko' is undefined    
knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js, line 16 character 3
SCRIPT5009: 'ko' is undefined 
myjs.js, line 1108 character 2
```

Comment: You might also want to post the code that's causing the error. Debugging it will be challenging otherwise.

Comment: my html  file contains 1050 lines

Comment: can I paste the error shown by IE9 debugger

Comment: To start with, just post the `head` tag.

Comment: Check out http://sscce.org/

Comment: sorry to asking this,where 'sscce.org' is placed

Comment: Did you click on the link?

Comment: ^lol. if you visit the link you will know what he's asking